# Retrieve newest record from inner join table

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Currently using an inner join to pull transaction records.  This is causing the left side of the join to return values for each of the right side table values.
*Without the inner join, single records are being returned from the left side table.
With the inner join right side table, a left record is being returned for each of the right side records.

> Do you know how to distinguish the "newest" record from the right table? Is there any timestamp column, ID or something like that?

Yes, there is a sequence number.

Ideal solution would be return only a single left row, and the newest record in the right table.

Comment: Do you know how to distinguish the "newest" record from the *right* table? Is there any timestamp column, ID or something like that? Because, if there's not, you can't do what you want.

Comment: Yes, there is a sequence number in that table

Comment: It's always helpful to include a reproducible test case.  The DDL to create the two tables, DML to insert some data, and the expected results in this case.

Comment: This is less of an `INNER` or `OUTER` join type of an issue and more of a "How do I only join on the latest record" type of an issue. If you aren't satisfied with the answer below, please include sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scant on details, but hopefully you can adapt this:

```
SELECT
  table_with_one_row t
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT u.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_group ORDER BY sequence_number DESC) rn
    FROM 
      table_with_multiple_rows_per_row_in_t u
  ) x
  ON
    t.id = x.id_group AND x.rn = 1
```